# How to trigger ipa installation completion event?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am downloading ipa using OpenUrlAsync. How I can get an event where the installation is completed.

```
 bool success = await UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrlAsync(
                downloadlink, options: new UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions());
```

Or Is there any other way to download an IPA and get installation completion event.

Comment: If you use `OpenUrlAsync`,the installing process is controlled by the system. It seems there is no api to intercept the process to get the progress or result.